# Contradictory system of linear inequalities

Tags: inequality, linear-programming

Assume that $(F_i)_i$ is a system of linear inequalities in 
$n$ variables, of the form $F_i(x_1,\ldots, x_n) > 0$, where 
$F_i(x_1, \ldots, x_n) = a_{i,1}x_1 + a_{i,2} x_2 +\ldots + a_{i,n} x_n + c_i$.
One way to prove that this system is contradictory (assuming it is) would be to show that there exists a linear combination $\sum_i \lambda _i F_i = -K$, with $K\geq0$ an $\lambda_i \geq 0 $ for all $i$.

I am wondering if the converse is not true: "if the system is contradictory, there *must* exist a linear positive combination of the $F_i$ that is equal to $-K$ for some $K\geq 0$".

Answer (score 0):

The answer is Yes. 
See [Fourier-Motzkin Elimination and Its Dual, GEORGE B. DANTZIG AND B. CURTIS EAVES](http://ac.els-cdn.com/0097316573900046/1-s2.0-0097316573900046-main.pdf?_tid=4b3701dc-3456-11e6-b073-00000aacb35d&acdnat=1466145771_765dda690158de831f3720cd7015d4ff)  
(Feasibility theorem).