# On linear systems of inequalities: stability and continuous dependence

Tags: inequality, linear-programming

Let $A$ be a $m\times n$ matrix and $b\in\mathbb{R}^m$ a vector, which define the set
$$
S(A,b):=\{x\in\mathbb{R}^n\::\:Ax\leq b\}.
$$

1. Let $A_k\to A$ and $b_k\to b$, w.r.t. some norm, such that all the sets $S(A_k,b_k)$ are non-empty. Can the non-emptyness of S(A,b) be concluded?
2. If $S(A,b)$ is non-empty, and $A'$ and $b'$ are "near enough" $A$ and $b$, respectively, can we say something about the non-emptyness of $S(A',b')$?

Edit: Item 1 is very simple when considering "$=$" instead of "$\leq$". The answer for item 1 is "no" in the equality case: is enough to consider $A_k=1/k$, $b_k=1$, so each solution set $\{x\::\:A_kx=b_k\}=\{k\}$ is non-empty but the "limit" solution set is $\{x\::\:0\cdot x=1\}=\emptyset$. But for the inequality case I couldn't find a counter example. I believe item 1 is true, here is my attempt to prove it: first observe that $S(A,b)\neq\emptyset$ if and only if
$$
\forall\,y\geq 0,\,y^{\top}b\geq 0\text{ or }A^{\top}y\neq 0.
$$
This is the "Feasibility Theorem" found [here](http://ac.els-cdn.com/0097316573900046/1-s2.0-0097316573900046-main.pdf?_tid=4b3701dc-3456-11e6-b073-00000aacb35d&acdnat=1466145771_765dda690158de831f3720cd7015d4ff) (I actually found this reference by having a look at [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1828928/contradictory-system-of-linear-inequalities)).

Second, for $y\geq 0$, denote 
$$
I(y)=\{k\in\mathbb{N}\::\:y^{\top}b_k\geq 0\}\text{ and }J(y)=\{k\in\mathbb{N}\::\:A_k^{\top}y\neq 0\}.
$$
Since $S(A_k,b_k)\neq \emptyset$ for all $k$, we have that $\mathbb{N}=I(y)\cup J(y)$, for all $y\geq 0$.

Now, given $y\geq 0$, then either $I(y)$ or $J(y)$ is infinite. If $I(y)$ is infinite, I can take the limit to the inequality $y^{\top}b_k\geq 0$ and obtain $y^{\top}b\geq 0$. However I cannot do the same when $J(y)$ is infinite, as I cannot conclude that $A^{\top}y\neq 0$ when $A_k^{\top}y\neq 0$ for $k\in J(y)$.

Comment: [Welcome to Math.SE!](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/11168/290189) Please read [this post](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9960/290189) and the others there for information on writing a good question for this site. In particular, people will be more willing to help if you [edit] your question to include some motivation, and an explanation of your own attempts.

Comment: I can only answer the second question: sometimes, yes. An example can be found in R. G. Bland, D. Goldfarb, and M. J. Todd. The ellipsoid method: A survey. Operations Research, 29(6) 1039-1091, 1981.

Comment: @LinAlg Thank you for the reference, I'll take a look at it.

Comment: I've found a counter example for item 1. Consider $A_k=\begin{bmatrix} -1 &0\\ 1 & -1/k\end{bmatrix}$, which converges to $A=\begin{bmatrix}-1& 0\\1 & 0\end{bmatrix}$ and $b_k=\begin{bmatrix}0\\-1\end{bmatrix}=b$. Each $S(A_k,B_k)\neq \emptyset$ but $S(A,b)=\emptyset$.

Comment: @MartenTang well done! I conjectured #1 to be true.